# Clarification TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, typeerror

I dont understand why I keep getting this error, I've read through similar posts stating that its because redefining the str or print function, but I dont understand what that means, can someone help explain?

```
ev_data = [['vehicle', 'range', 'price'],
           ['Tesla Model 3 LR', '310', '49900'],
           ['Hyundai Ioniq EV', '124', '30315'],
           ['Chevy Bolt', '238', '36620']]

for row in ev_data[1:]:         # loop through each row in ev_data starting with row 2 (index 1)
    ev_range = row[1]           # each car's range is found in column 2 (index 1)
    ev_range = int(ev_range)    # convert each range number from a string to an integer
    row[1] = ev_range           # assign range, which is now an integer, back to index 1 in each row

print(ev_data)

total_range = 0

for row in ev_data[1:]:
    ev_range = row[1]
    total_range += ev_range

number_of_cars = len(ev_data[1:])
a = (total_range / number_of_cars)
print("Total average range is:"(a))
```

Comment: where did you get the error? (see stacktrace). I don't see any "str" being called nor being redefined in your code. Also, it seems that you used python, so please add appropriate tag

Comment: thanks tag added, the error is at the very last line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On your final line:

```
print("Total average range is:"(a))
```

you're trying to call `"Total average range is:"` as if it is a function.

You want to convert `a` to a string and concatenate it:

```
print("Total average range is:" + str(a))
```

Alternatively you can use an [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
print(f"Total average range is: {a}")
```